# Converting dataset to list of libraries to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataset, libraries

I have a dataset concatenated_df that I need to convert to a list of libraries. The end goal is to be able to call upon the libraries to create a plot using matplotlib. The dataset consists of many CSV files sorted by date and are read with pandas.

input

`concatenated_df`

output is the dataset of all the CSV files

I tried something along the lines of

`dictionary = concatenated_df.to_dict(orient='records')`

to convert the dataset to dictionaries and it returns but it is rather messy. There is a lot of junk columns I dont need.
Is is possible to just pull certain named columns from the dataset into the libraries and then plot them using matplotlib?
In short I have a dataset to convert to libraries so that I can plot them. I cant really post more code because the CSV files are imported from MyDrive. Its rather convoluted and I am new at this so if there is confusion please let me know and Ill try my best to clarify.